# Adjusting observations' weights to deal with missing values in logistic regression

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am working on a binary classification problem where one of the important explanatory variables has substantial missing values. To deal with this, I estimated a logistic model to predict whether or not the value for that variable is missing, and then use the probabilities that I get from this model as weights for the observations when estimating my actual model of interest. This way, I would get rid of the observations with the missing values and just use the rest of the observations as adjusted with the weights.

I searched a bit. The `class_weight` hyperparameter of `LogisticRegression` doesn't seem to fit my need, so any suggestions are welcome. I would also appreciate your opinion on this approach, I am trying to go through all the available methods and see which one gives the best results.

Comment: this is more of a math question than a programming question tbh

Comment: Mmm maybe, but it could boiled down to this : when estimating the model with the default settings, it's as if all observations are equally represented. What I'm trying to do is simply change the weights of each observation.

Comment: yea, what you're trying to do there will need to be built into your regression model. thus, math.

Comment: It turns out the `glm` function in R has a `weights` parameter that allows you to that, I think that solves my problem